# Detect the version of CloudFoundry/Bluemix

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I am trying to detect the version of Bluemix/Cloud Foundry. Is there a command I can use to do this?

cf -version tells you the version of the commandline interface, but not the version of the server you are "push"ing to.

thanks

anthony

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the version of CloudFoundry that Bluemix is running on via the CloudFoundry info endpoint.

US South Datacenter - https://api.ng.bluemix.net/info (currently 226 as of this posting)

EU UK Datacenter - https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net/info (currently 226 as of this posting)

AP Datacenter - https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net/info (currently 226 as of this posting)

AP Datacenter - https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net/info (currently 226 as of this posting)

The build is the bit of JSON you want.

```
{
"name": "Bluemix",
"build": "226004",
"support": "http://ibm.com",
"version": 2,
"description": "IBM Bluemix",
"authorization_endpoint": "https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR",
"token_endpoint": "https://uaa.ng.bluemix.net",
"allow_debug": true
}
```

Comment: When I click the link, I get a message saying "forbidden".  Refreshing the page in the browser clears it up.  How to get from "build" and "version" to CloudFoundry release number?

Comment: I modified my answer. The build field is the info you want.

Comment: @lmsurprenant, not sure why those links fail when clicked from the answer, but when I copy/paste the link into a new browser session, I was able to get a subset of the information returned from `cf curl /v2/info`.  You can also just use `curl https://api.ng.bluemix.net/info` to get the same info.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the command `cf curl /v2/info` to access Bluemix's Cloud Controller endpoint to get info about versions, etc.  Here's the output I see at the moment:

```
$ cf curl /v2/info
{
   "name": "Bluemix",
   "build": "195008",
   "support": "http://ibm.com",
   "version": 2,
   "description": "IBM Bluemix",
   "authorization_endpoint": "https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR",
   "token_endpoint": "https://uaa.ng.bluemix.net",
   "api_version": "2.19.0",
   "logging_endpoint": "wss://loggregator.ng.bluemix.net:443",
   "user": "<uuid>"
}
```

The `build` property's first three characters map to the version of Cloud Foundry in use.  In this case, version 195, which corresponds to the versioned API doc here: http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/195/