# Error deploying Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: ibm-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to deploy Spring Cloud Data Flow in IBM Bluemix. 
I followed all the instructions in the reference docs 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

This is the error I end up

[CELL/0]     ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.

I tried with multiple releases and snapshot version without luck.

```
2017-05-08T10:54:33.84-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:33.847  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [schema-h2-deployment.sql] in 4 ms.
2017-05-08T10:54:35.07-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:35.067  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2017-05-08T10:54:35.43-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:35.426  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql] in 47 ms.
2017-05-08T10:54:35.44-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:35.446  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/schema-h2.sql] in 10 ms.
2017-05-08T10:54:38.75-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:38.735 DEBUG 6 --- [           main] cloudfoundry-client.request              : GET    https://api.ng.bluemix.net:443/v2/info
2017-05-08T10:54:38.83-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:38.832  WARN 6 --- [           main] io.netty.util.internal.MacAddressUtil    : Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 9d:fe:c3:22:e8:92:e0:8e
2017-05-08T10:54:40.07-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:40.072 DEBUG 6 --- [ry-client-nio-1] cloudfoundry-client.token                : Negotiating using token provider
2017-05-08T10:54:40.07-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:40.073 DEBUG 6 --- [ry-client-nio-1] cloudfoundry-client.request              : GET    https://api.ng.bluemix.net:443/v2/info
2017-05-08T10:54:40.26-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:40.259 DEBUG 6 --- [ry-client-nio-1] cloudfoundry-client.response             : 200    https://api.ng.bluemix.net:443/v2/info (183 ms)
2017-05-08T10:54:40.30-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:40.301 DEBUG 6 --- [ry-client-nio-1] cloudfoundry-client.request              : POST   https://login.ng.bluemix.net:443/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token
2017-05-08T10:55:09.02-0500 [CELL/0]     ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.
2017-05-08T10:55:09.03-0500 [CELL/0]     OUT Exit status 0
2017-05-08T10:55:09.07-0500 [APP/0]      OUT Exit status 143
2017-05-08T10:55:09.13-0500 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 2c368dc4-c1a3-4d22-90c7-79f4e17c02e3 payload: {"instance"=>"", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 1 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Exited with status 4\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", "crash_count"=>2, "crash_timestamp"=>1494258909081338043, "version"=>"36ff0230-4b77-480f-84b4-75e95eeb1a51"}
```

**I see some errors in Debug Mode**

```
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 16:15:28.207 DEBUG 7 --- [           main] io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl             : Failed to initialize netty-tcnative; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable. See http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html for more information.
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: provided (Not found in java.library.path)
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:180) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.initializeTcNative(OpenSsl.java:417) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:101) ~[netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:117) [netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:113) [netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:747) [netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:406) [netty-all-4.1.8.Final.jar!/:4.1.8.Final]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient.create(HttpClient.java:71) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.reactor._DefaultConnectionContext.getHttpClient(_DefaultConnectionContext.java:80) [cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.DefaultConnectionContext.access$1501(DefaultConnectionContext.java:23) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.DefaultConnectionContext$InitShim.getHttpClient(DefaultConnectionContext.java:108) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.DefaultConnectionContext$Builder.build(DefaultConnectionContext.java:877) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.4.0.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6790603.CGLIB$connectionContext$4(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.1.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6790603$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c5e22cf8.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.1.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6790603.connectionContext(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.1.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryDataFlowServer.main(CloudFoundryDataFlowServer.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[app/:na]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[app/:na]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[app/:na]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.22-0500 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[app/:na]
2017-05-08T11:15:28.31-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 16:15:28.292 DEBUG 7 --- [           main] javax.security.sasl                      :
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear which version of CF OSS release that your Bluemix install builds upon. Please have a look at the compatibility matrix [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/). Spring Cloud Data Flow should be compatible starting from CF-239 release versions.

If your Bluemix install is indeed compatible, you could enable DEBUG logs for CF-Java-Client by setting `JAVA_OPTS: '-Dlogging.level.cloudfoundry-client=DEBUG'` env-var for SCDF's CF-server. It would be easy to troubleshoot what's causing the health checks to fail.

Comment: The current build is 235.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644655/detect-the-version-of-cloudfoundry-bluemix.  The build is the first three characters in the build field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the Bluemix version is 235. Does that mean Spring Cloud Data Flow is not compatible at this point on Bluemix? Are there any alternatives.

Comment: Though it is not a supported version, we still have a CI-plan running against CF-235 (PCF 1.7) and it is green. I'd try enabling the DEBUG logs to see what's the root cause for health check failures.

Comment: I added logs to the Original question, I see java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError and 2017-05-08T10:54:38.83-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-05-08 15:54:38.832  WARN 6 --- [           main] io.netty.util.internal.MacAddressUtil    : Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 9d:fe:c3:22:e8:92:e0:8e

Comment: I was made aware of [cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#739](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/739) - this fix specifically addresses the original problem. The [1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_download_the_spring_cloud_data_flow_server_and_shell_apps) of CF-server already [builds](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/blob/master/pom.xml#L22) on this fix. Please try it out and share your findings.

Comment: I tried with 1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT as well, health check still fails, ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed

Comment: Turns out, the 1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is _still_ not building against the latest version. I created [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry#328](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/issues/328) for tracking. In the meantime, you can change the version manually from 1.2.0.RC1 to 1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/blob/master/pom.xml#L17). Also, you'd have to change the Reactor to `3.0.7`. With these 2 version changes, you can locally build the CF-server via `mvn clean package`.